# need help "translating" these sql into django models

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-models

i am very new with gae and i havent find an easy to follow example.

here is my sql:

```
CREATE TABLE Company
(
    name varchar(100),
    address varchar(100),
    lat double(20, 10),
    long double(20, 10),
    phone varchar(15),
    website varchar(50),
    email varchar(50),
    hiring boolean not null default 0 ,
    about_us varchar(500),
    approved boolean not null default 0
)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just asking what should the django model look like. Then I think you want a class like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
  lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10, null=True)
  long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10, null=True)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
  website = models.UrlField(max_length=50, null=True)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True)
  hiring = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  about_us = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
  approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```